# Как объявить массив numpy с заданным размером?

Tags: python, numpy

Мне надо создать массив типа `(3, 3, 1)`. Когда я объявляю `data = np.array([[[]]])`, то размер массива `(1, 1, 0)`.

Нормально, задать размер массиву можно только, если сразу при создании записать в него значения, но мне это не подходит, т. к. массив я заполняю дальше в коде. При попытке изменить параметр `shape` студия выдает ошибку:

> cannot reshape array of size 0 into shape (3,3,1)

Как объявить массив numpy размером `(3,3,1)` без заполнения сразу при создании?

Comment: np.empty((3, 3, 1))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### [Вариант 1](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.empty.html): неинициализированные значения

```
a = np.empty((3,3,1))
```

#### [Вариант 2](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html): нули

```
a = np.zeros((3,3,1))
```

#### [Вариант 3](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.full.html#numpy.full): заполняем значением (параметр: `fill_value` )

```
a = np.full((3,3,1), fill_value=np.nan)
```

PS в первом варианте значения матрицы могут иметь случайные (неинициализированные) значения.

Comment: Спасибо, это помогло.

Comment: Не знал про `np.empty`, он, похоже, подхватывает свободную память, если перед ним сделать `np.ones` или `np.zeros` такого же размера и освободить, то он их подхватит, а так там какая-то ботва если память произвольная )